# EventBus Unable to start activity

Tags: android, event-bus

I'm building an app Android and I want to send an EventBus from my Service class to my Activity.

So this is my activity code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startServiceScan(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(BlePowerService.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(BlePowerService.class);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(BlePowerService.class);
    }

// This method will be called when a HelloWorldEvent is posted
    public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){
        // your implementation
        System.out.print("");
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void getEventBusData(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        if (messageEvent != null) {
           //TO-DO
        }

    }
```

This is the code in my BlePowerService class:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("update"));
```

if I try to start my application, I have this error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.care.devicesensor/com.care.devicesensor.BLEActivity}: 
org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class java.lang.Class and its super classes have 
no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
...............
Caused by: org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class java.lang.Class 
and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
```

The error id onStart method from my Activity class.

//EDIT

I add my MessageEvent class:

```
public class MessageEvent {
    public final String message;

    public MessageEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using proGuard?

Comment: Please post your MessageEvent class

Comment: No I don't use proGuard. I have insert in my gradle file this line code:
 implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have done a few things wrong here...

First, looking at [Androids activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc), if you register something in `onStart()` you should then unregister it in `onStop()`, and if you register something in `onResume()` you should then unregister it in `onPause()`. Otherwise, you register it when the the activity starts but when the user puts the app into the background for a bit, it will unregister, and it will not register again as the app hasn't started, it has just resumed.

Secondly, if you look at the [EventBus GitHub](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) you should be registering the Activity and not a class.

Here is an example:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

Now you can call the `onMessageEvent` function from anywhere in the app with the code:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("update"));
```

On an extra note, this could be a result of your ProGuard. Luckily there are [EventBus ProGuard rules](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/proguard/) we can use to prevent subscribers from being removed from your code:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with what version of EventBus you are using please. And I will update my answer with some more information todo with proguard.

Answer (score 2):

The below code working perfectly in my end

Activity code where you want to received event

```
@Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }
 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }

 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
  public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
      // do your code
  }
```

Code in service class

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("event"));
```

You have to pass current  **class instance in the register & unregister** eventbus.

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like from the exception message, you are trying to register `EventBus` inside a `BLEActivity` while you are passing `BlePowerService` to `EventBus.getDefault().register();` which might not have the `@Subscribe` annotation.

You should try

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

inside `BLEActivity` since this activity has the `@Subscribe` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Try register in

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(BlePowerService.class);
    }
```

and unregister in

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(BlePowerService.class);
    }
```

remove in all other method.